# How to load local static files if CDN fails? (django)

Tags: python, django, cdn

I am using django to develop my site and I am trying to optimize my site for speed so I want to use CDN for my bootstrap and if it fails than i want to use the copy from my server, I have seen
[How to load local files if CDN is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077276/how-to-load-local-files-if-cdn-is-not-working)
but it does it in javascript but it doesn't solve my problem, I want to know
    **how to check if CDN working with Django and if not serve the static files from server?**

Comment: Just use a reliable CDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do not try to do this in server-side. CDN services are built to be reliable in that they are geographically distributed and fault-tolerant and use the best practices available.**

You can't find out if the CDN servers work *for your user* by pinging them *from your Django application*. Your user is located differently and might have very different network conditions, e.g. be using a mobile network connection from a different country, and have a network provider that experiences outages.

You could, indeed, ping the CDN servers, which would probably resolve into your Django application getting one CDN load balancer address and trying to see if that works for you or not, and falling back to others, if the CDN source is down. Then you would probably have to see, for **every resource you have**, that is **every JavaScript and CSS file**, if they are available, and load a local backup, if not. On the server side. **This is very slow and error-prone. Networks can fail for a googolplex different reasons.**

The proper way to go about this is to

- Only use local servers for serving those static files, distribute the load with application servers that each have their own versioned copies of your static files. If your application server works, it should have the copies available as well;
- Do the checks on the client-side, because server side queries will slow your server down to a halt if it is not close to your CDN network, and you generally do not wish to depend on any external resources on the server side;
- Or, as I would recommend, set up your own CDN which serves your local files from a proxied URL or subdomain. Read more below.

Ideally, if you wish to use a reliable CDN source, you would set up a CDN server with redundancy on the same infrastructure you use to host your files in.

For  your site is located in www.example.com, which is your Django application server address. You would set up cdn.example.com domain which would be a CDN service, for example CloudFront or similar, that proxies your requests to www.example.com/static/ and mirrors your static files as a CDN, taking the load off your application server. You can just define your Django application to use the http://cdn.example.com/static address for serving static files. **There are multiple different services for providing a CDN for your application, CloudFront is just one option.** This will get your static, CDNable files near to your user.

Ideally, your application servers and CDN servers are hosted on the same, redundant infrastructure, and you can claim that if one part of your infrastructure works the others will as well, or other your service provider is violating your SLA. You do NOT wish to use broken infrastructure and drive away your customers, or use hacks that will eventually break in production.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there would be a good way of doing this, but this is the method I would use if the people who paid me *really* wanted me to make this work

You could setup custom URL tags in a separate pluggable app, and have it ping your CDN target, and then if it fails, serve a local URI. Admittedly, pinging the CDN target doesn't mean it will actually serve the file, so a more robust way would be to attempt to GET the file from the CDN provider, and and if successful, send the remote URI, and if it fails, send the local URI. This would double the traffic of your static files for every request.

This also requires you to setup static file serving just like you would if you planned to serve everything from that server. I wouldn't recommend any of this. I would recommend doing what @ceejayoz says and just using a reliable CDN. That's their whole purpose in life is to prevent doing any of this.

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable, but the setup might be a little tedious.

Basically you are trying to do failover between CDN and your origin server. If CDN fails, the request fails over to your origin server. One option is to use DNS level failover with primary to CDN CNAME, backup to your origin server hostname.

And you also include healthcheck in your DNS setup for both CDN and origin server. Once healthcheck fails for CDN, DNS should fail over to your origin server and serve static file from there automatically.